# How to do debugging in a Python console without reloading the package in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, module, pycharm

PyCharm runs an interactive Python console (IPython in my case), but when I make changes in the code, PyCharm doesn't reimport the modules I've been editing, so the console runs the old code.

More so, if I have an old package installed via `Run setup.py Task`, Python imports the old one after `import mymodule as mm` in the console.

One workaround is to edit the code in a file and rerun it without the interactive console, but that's not a very elegant solution.

How can I keep the interactive console up-to date and update modules on-the-fly?

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but in the python console you can type `reload(module)`, being module a module object. I find it quite handy.

Comment: I'd add that for Python 3, it's: `import imp;
imp.reload(module)`

Comment: So, did it solve the problem?

Comment: @Anton note that as of 2020-09-18 in pyton3.8 the package `imp` is deprecated in favour of `importlib` see Chaffelson answer below

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Python 3.4.3 in Pycharm 4.0.6 currently, and building on Anton's answer above, I add the following to my Starting script:

```
from importlib import reload
```

then you can simply use 'reload(my_module)' as you please - however this would be manual for each reload and I'm not aware of a fully automated solution if that's what you're really after.

Comment: I believe IPython's deepreload does what you want, and although you might need to add an import hook to make sure that it recursively reloads dependent modules.

Answer (score 1):

IPython has a very nice function that recursively reloads all modules. It is called `dreload`, from *deep reload*. You just have to manually run in the console:

```
dreload(myCoolModule)
```

It is manual, but it doesn't bothers me.  If I remember well, it doesn't work if you remove the namespace importing like: `from myCoolModule import *`